# Wrong dimensions while transposing a Matrix in Java

Tags: java, matrix

I need to transpose the following Matrix:

```
Matrix o = new Matrix(new int[][] { { 1, 4, 6 }, { 2, 4, -1 },
            { 0, 4, 0 }, { 5, 1, 0 } });
```

Currently I'm using this code:

```
public void transpose() {

    for(int i = 0; i < values[i].length; i++) {
        for(int j = i+1; j < values[j].length; j++) {
            int t = values[i][j];
            values[i][j] = values[j][i];
            values[j][i] = t;
        }
    }
```

The resulting Matrix is 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/if7HA.png

while the resulting Matrix should be like this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nKbx.png

I appreciate any help I can get, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include the desired and actual results *in text* in the question. There's no need to use images here.

Comment: But as a hint - how do you expect this to change the shape of the array? Basically you should be returning a new `int[][]` rather than trying to transpose in-place.

Comment: [idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Please include the observed and desired behaviour as text in your question instead of external links to images.

Answer (score 0):

You need a new 2d array instance:

```
int[][] T = new int[ values[1].length ][ values.length ];
    for( int i = 0; i < T.length; i++ ) {
      for( int j = 0; j < T[1].length; j++ ) {
        T[ i ][ j ] = values[ j ][ i ];
        System.out.print( T[ i ][ j ] + "\t" );
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
```

Output:

```
1 2 0 5 
4 4 4 1 
6 -1  0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues here. As Jon pointed out, your starting array is a 3x4, while your desired output array is a 4x3. You need to create a new target array to store your values in. The dimensions of this should be calculated from the input array dimensions. Examine how many times each of your loops run, and how many times SHOULD it run. You should find the answer jumps out at you.